# Finding out if admin consented for use of Web Application Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to find out if admin consented to allowing Web application to be allowed in their tenant directory ?

Basically, I have a Web application and I want only admin to consent on behalf of all users. If I use `prompt=admin_consent` in authentication request it works great and only admins can consent.

But every time application is accessed, the same prompt re-appears even after the application got provisioned in their directory

I could solve this issue by kind of creating an on-boarding page where I collect from them tenant id and seeing if its registered and if yes don't ask to prompt again and simply proceed with authentication.

But is there anyway this thing comes for free or is there anything in the token that tells if this user is admin user or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there anyway this thing comes for free or is there anything in
>   the token that tells if this user is admin user or not ?

I'm sure you can find user roles using graph API however I don't think this will help your case as the consent part happens on Azure AD itself before the user information is returned back to your application.

---

We faced exact same problem with our application and here's how we tried to solve it. See if this approach makes sense to you.

We have two different URLs for our application: One for signing up and other for signing in.

During the sign up process when we send the user to Azure AD for authentication, we append `prompt=admin_consent` to the URL so that only users in admin roles can sign up. After they sign up, we get the user information back and along with that we get the tenant id back. What we do is store the tenant id in our database. During the sign up process, we ask them to pick a name for their account which could be anything. Along with tenant id we store this information as well. Once the sign up process is complete, we create a unique URL for this account (something like `https://my-app.com/{account-name}/sign-in`) and this is something the account admin (person who signed up) can give to their team members.

When a team member accesses the application using the sign in URL, we extract the team name from the URL and find out the Azure AD tenant id based on that and redirect the user to Azure AD tenant (`https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}`) for signing in. At this time, we don't include `prompt=admin_consent` in the URL.

Comment: Sad they don't return anything that gives this information